# Report Analysis Services 2008 Olap

Tags: sql-server-2008, row, ssrs-2008, dimensions

Good afternoon,

I need to display the information splitted in columns in Analisys services 2008 OLAP report as follows:

```
IdNumber Name  LastName  IdNumber Name  LastName  IdNumber  Name   LastName
1        Ana   Perez     3        Pedro Perez     5         Carlos Perez
2        Jose  Jose      4        Carlo Carlos    6         Ana    Rijo
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks what you are trying to achieve is a "newspaper-style" report.

This is possible in [Reporting Services 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155816%28SQL.100%29.aspx) (and also [in 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155816%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)).

See "[How to: Create a Newsletter-Style Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)" from SQL Books Online for complete instructions, but basically you need to set the **Columns** property of the Report to indicate how many columns you wish the report to have.

Also note the restriction that only the Image and PDF renderers support newsletter-style layout. Other renderers just render the output as a single column